# Decimal expansion__Represent numbers as $x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{b^k}$?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

If $b>1$ is an integer, is well know that the numbers $x\in (0,1]$, can be written as
$$x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{b^k}$$
for some integers $a_k \in \{0,1,\ldots ,b-1\} $.

My problem is how to prove that? How to show that exist such integers $a_k$?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that it is true for **all real values** in the range $(0,1]$. In fact, I'm quite sure that it is false for **all transcendental values** in that range.

Comment: @barakmanos What kind of number would $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n!}$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to write
$$
x=0,a_1a_2a_3\dots\text{ in base }b.
$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
b\cdot x&=\phantom{a_2a_3}a_1,a_2a_3\dots\\
b^2\cdot x&=\phantom{a_3}a_1a_2,a_3\dots\\
b^3\cdot x&=a_1a_2a_3,\dots
\end{align}$$
and so on. Define
$$
a_n=\mod([b^n\cdot x],b)
$$
where $[\,\cdot\,]$ is the integer part function. I leave it to you to prove that in fact
$$
x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{b^n}.
$$